# click element on website/python/webdriver/beautifulsoap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I want to make test automation on website. I have a problem with finding/clicking element. Tried to find it by `driver.find_by (many combinations)` and with BeautifulSoap.

this element I want to click/choose:
`<div id="listOfTalksName">Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz</div>`

Tried:
`soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div id="listOfTalksName">Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz</div></body></html', "html.parser")` but have no idea what to do next. My tries with `driver.find_by` also seems to be wrong.

I am using Python 3.8.0, with webdriver and BeautifulSoap installed.
Please help, I got stuck. Could you please explain how to find elements on website?

EDIT:
below is my site code:
[site][1]

EDIT2: my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from csv import DictReader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import lxml
import itertools

#here is irrelevant part

#unable to locate:
#driver.find_element_by_tag_name("listOfTalksName").click()
#driver.find_element_by_link_text("Zofia").click()
#driver.find_element_by_link_text("listOfTalksName").click()
#driver.find_element_by_name("Zofia").click()#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("listOfTalksReaded").click()
#driver.find_element_by_link_text("Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="listOfTalksName"]/a[text()="Zofia"]').click()
#result_one = driver.find_element_by_id("listOfTalksReaded")
#result = result_one.find_element_by_name("Zofia").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@class='listOfTalksName'" and text()='Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz').click()

#soup = ('<html><body><div id="listOfTalksName"> "Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz" </div></body></html')
#soup.find("div", {"id": "listOfTalksName"}).click()
#div = BeautifulSoup.find(id="listOfTalksName").get()
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div id="listOfTalksName">Zofia Achmistrowiczwachmistrowicz</div></body></html', "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("div", id=re.compile("^listOfTalksName")))

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRd2.png
```

Comment: For automation, use Selenium. BeautifulSoup is for parsing html.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find it by driver.find_by xpath, id, css selector, partial text but all failed. Tried also to connect 2 driver.find_by (id+partial text). Could you please help me find it by selenium webdriver?

Comment: @sarasa can you post the real site itself?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have edited post, please check